# When trying to use turbo console log , variable gets replaced by character

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new in visual studio code. I was seeking for useful plugins for vs code and I found that [Turbo Console Log](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChakrounAnas.turbo-console-log) is a good one.

Now after installing, inside settings.json, I did some changes,

```
  "turboConsoleLog.wrapLogMessage":true,
  "turboConsoleLog.insertEnclosingFunction":true,
  "turboConsoleLog.includeFileNameAndLineNum":true,
```

Also I noticed that Turbo Console Log is there and `ctrl+alt+L` is not have any conflicts with others.
[image]

Now when I am trying to use by selecting the word and then press `ctrl+alt+L`,

the variable replaced by  `̥`

[image]

Did anyone face similar issue??

Edit:

Command Palette
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Command Palette: `Turbo Console Log: Display Log Message`

Comment: Hi @rioV8 , thanks for Your response and yes I have tried it too. I have updated the thread , please have a look :)

Comment: have you executed the command from the palette to see if it works

Comment: @rioV8 No I didn't but as mentioned in answer, I have changed the key bindings and it is working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok ,
By the help of [this link](https://github.com/Chakroun-Anas/turbo-console-log/issues/35) I am able to override the settings, currently mine is,
keybindings.json

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+2",
        "command": "turboConsoleLog.displayLogMessage"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+3",
        "command": "turboConsoleLog.deleteAllLogMessages"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+4",
        "command": "turboConsoleLog.commentAllLogMessages"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+6",
        "command": "turboConsoleLog.uncommentAllLogMessages"
    },
```

My console right now:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

While I am aware that changing keyboard shortcut is the preferred solution,the root cause of this problem is with the keyboard language.When I switched to English (UK) keyboard, this problem didn't persist.Now there might be other keyboards that might not have this problem,English(UK) is the one I know so far to be free from this issue.

You can switch keyboards from the bottom right language option in the taskbar or press `Windows + Space`

Answer (score 2):

I Was using a plugin called Bookmarks. That was conflicted with. So I removed it.

Comment: I had the same extension, and yes it creates a conflict that makes the command for inserting log not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. ctrl+shift+p and search open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)
2. It will open file keybinding.json
3. paste this and custom shortcut you want to change

   {
   "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
   "command": "turboConsoleLog.displayLogMessage"
   },
   {
   "key": "ctrl+shift+d",
   "command": "turboConsoleLog.deleteAllLogMessages"
   },
   {
   "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
   "command": "turboConsoleLog.commentAllLogMessages"
   },
   {
   "key": "ctrl+shift+u",
   "command": "turboConsoleLog.uncommentAllLogMessages"
   }